# Microservice that starts up other microservices

Tags: microservices

I currently have a monolith application, which has a thread running per customer. Each time a new customer registers, you start up a new thread; each time they send in information (make an order, change details,etc.) The message is routed to the correct thread; and each time they unregister the thread shuts itself down.

I have a routing thread that does the thread and message management.

It seems, with my limited knowledge of microservices, that this is a prime candidate for converting to a microservices architecture - I have a set of independent processes (customer threads) running.

As I start looking into it, I was thinking of creating one service that is the equivalent of the "customer thread" - `customer microservice instance`.

How would you go about spinning up a new `customer microservice instance` each time a new customer comes along? You could have some kind of `manager microservice`, but given that the idea is to distribute the `customer microservice instance`s "in the cloud" (i.e. we shouldn't care about where they are?) This doesn't quite seem to fit with what I've read about microservices and how they work. Or have I misunderstood something? What would be the best approach for distributing this system?

One approach I have considered is having the `manager microservice` contact a "process starter" service round-robin. the `process starter` service would have an instance running on each physical server (or in each container), which then starts local `customer microservice instance`s - but from what I was reading you shouldn't really share a container with multiple microservices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may become too opinion-based for Stack Overflow - but I'll give it a go.

The most common definition of a microservice architecture I'm aware of is "a group of small, focused services operating in a bounded context, which are composed to deliver end-to-end functionality to business processes." Your "thread per customer" approach is almost exactly the opposite of this - the thread appears to know everything about the customer, what they do and how they do it. The thread is the monolith.

In a microservice architecture, you would have services for specific contexts in the business domain, for instance `CustomerProfile`, `Orders`, `Invoices`, `CustomerService` etc.

In this model, you could still have a "thread per customer", but instead of baking the knowledge of how to place an order into the thread itself, the thread invokes a microservice (probably over HTTP). The thread is responsible for state management and orchestrating the microservices to achieve the end-to-end business functionality.

Each microservice would be as independent as possible; it's common for each microservice to have its own container(s) and deployment architecture.

Again, mostly opinion-base - if you decide to stay with "thread per customer", I would not want to spin up a new service for every customer - this would be very wasteful. I imagine most of your threads are asleep for the vast majority of their life; giving them their own service instance (and container to run in) would not make a lot of sense.

However, the answer to "how can I start a service instance" is handled typically by load balancing (the load balancer knows which instances are available, and routes requests based on whatever availability heuristic you choose). You can auto-scale on most cloud providers, or you can use tools like Kubernetes to manage the provisioning of containers and servers.

Comment: OK, so then probably what I want to do doesn't fit into the microservices philosophy. That's a valid answer I suppose :) In that case, perhaps I need to narrow the scope of my question  to `how can a service start up another service on a different server?` - or think about how to break down my existing `Customer` service into business domain services